# Is it possible to change difficulty mid-game?

Tags: civilization-5

Ive been playing games on prince difficulty level, I don't like higher difficulty levels as the AI tend to cheat and has an unfair advantage early in the game.

However later in the game, once I have built up a big enough empire, I tend to destroy the other civilizations with little difficulty. At this point, I wouldn't mind the AI being harder and doing a bit of cheating.

Is there anyway to start off on one difficulty level, and then later on, ramp it up?

Comment: Not ingame, maybe with save editing or something.

Comment: this save editing you speak of - how does it work? what magic is this?

Comment: literally opening the savefile/files in a program that can read it/them and change the correct part. No idea if it's even posible though.

Comment: if anybody knows of save file editors please let us know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple mods which can do this. I haven't personally used any so I can only recommend browsing the Steam Workshop and/or Google.

It is also possible to do this by saving the map in the World Builder then opening it as a scenario on the new difficulty. This does, however, cause some problems such as the AI forgetting parts of your diplomatic history.